# Interactive jobs via qsh not working in sge

Tags: qsub, sungridengine

Trying to launch an interactive job on host 0001 using qsh fails to start. Executing "qsh -q int.q -display 0001:10.0" gives the following output:

Your job 123 ("INTERACTIVE") has been submitted
Waiting for interactive job to be scheduled
Could not start the interactive job.

Run command on submission host 0001:
qsh -q int.q -display 0001:10.0

Expectation: New xterm connected to host 0002 would open.

What I've tried:
Command qsub -q int.q works correctly to submit a job from host 0001 to 0002.

I have set SELinux to permissive/disabled. I have disabled firewalld. Command ssh -X 0002 to execution host works. I can qsub jobs to queue int.q and they run fine. I can ping host 0002.

qlogin from host 0001 to 0002 works, but I cannot run any GUI applications, since DISPLAY is not set. Setting it manually to "0001:10.0" does not fix the situation.